# AngularJS: Modifying built-in validator doesn't work

Tags: regex, angularjs, validation

I am trying to modify Angular's built-in e-mail validator according to the official documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms, almost at the bottom of the page). They even provide a plunkr there which I forked and updated with REGEX expressions that should validate emails better than Angular's standard validation: http://plnkr.co/edit/UerAymIVWmAYKjeT3FH2?p=preview - works.

However, if I try to implement this code in my module, it doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/UerAymIVWmAYKjeT3FH2?p=preview.

So basically I've just replaced

`var app = angular.module('form-example-modify-validators', []);` with

`var App = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'ngCordova'])`.

Feels like am lacking some very basic understanding of Angular here, could anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Super stupid: Obviously the plunkr can't find my dependencies.